# Rails: custom error message for child object name in has_many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have two models:

```
Category
  has_many :inventories

Inventory
  belongs_to :category
```

If I am creating a **Category** and get errors, it now displays like:

```
Inventories unit of purchase can't be blank
```

How can I get this to say instead:

```
Inventory unit of purchase can't be blank
```

I've tried all kinds of combinations in en.yml and thought about an inflector rule, but can't seem to figure out the trick.

> EDIT

For en.yml, I've tried this:

```
activerecord:
  models:
    inventory: "Inventory"
```

Comment: It can be done by changing en.yml. Can you update the question with `en.yml` code

Comment: Also are you creating inventory along with category?

Comment: Yes, sorry -- forgot to say that Category accepts_nested_attributes for Inventory.

Comment: What is the field name in the inventory? `unit_of_purchase`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the attribute name of `Inventory` is `unit_of_purchase`, this should do

```
en:  
  activerecord:    
    errors:
      models:
        inventory:
          attributes:
            unit_of_purchase:
              blank: "can't be blank"
```

Comment: I think I was missing one level in my en.yml. thank you!